# How to prevent the status bar from appearing in an iPad screenshot?

Tags: ipad, screen-capture

So if I have this image:

[image: original]

And I don't want the status bar in the screenshot:

[image: not needed]

What should I do?
Is there an easy inbuilt way out to prevent that bar from appearing on all screenshots?
If not, then what would be the quickest way to crop it out using the iPad itself?

Comment: You can use `imagemagick` command line tool to remove them. For example: `convert input.png -chop 0x20 output.png`. `imagemagick` can be downloaded using homebrew, fink, macports etc.

Comment: I know nothing about homebrew and imagemagick for iPad. Can you get me started from some link? @MateuszSzlosek

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I thought You'd want to crop those images on Your Mac not the iPad. In this case please ignore my comment above.

Comment: FYI it's called the status bar, not notification panel.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to remove the status bar unless you are in an app which is full-screen and chooses to hide that information. However, you can crop the image in the Photos app:

1. Take Screenshot
2. Open Photos app
3. Open screenshot
4. Press Edit in upper-right of screen
5. Depending on rotation of screen, look for the Crop symbol
6. Press Crop and drag the white boxed frame to match the image you'd like
7. Press Done to finish cropping

[Here is a Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Crop-Photos-on-an-iPad-With-the-Photos-App) on how to do it, with screenshots.